# From MYSQL result to JSON: unable to create right JSON

Tags: php, json

I have this results from MySQL:

```
+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
| SUPPLIED_AMOUNT | DATE_ISO | DATE_JAVASCRIPT |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
| 5919.00         | 20150716 |   1436994000000 |
| 4389.00         | 20150717 |   1437080400000 |
| 12069.00        | 20150718 |   1437166800000 |
| 10220.00        | 20150720 |   1437339600000 |
| 9444.00         | 20150721 |   1437426000000 |
| 8630.00         | 20150722 |   1437512400000 |
| 9009.00         | 20150723 |   1437598800000 |
| 7324.00         | 20150724 |   1437685200000 |
| 4295.00         | 20150725 |   1437771600000 |
| 4398.00         | 20150726 |   1437858000000 |
| 3385.00         | 20150727 |   1437944400000 |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
```

I need to convert to a similar json:

```
[1253145600000,26.36],
[1253232000000,26.43],
[1253491200000,26.29],
[1253577600000,26.35],
[1253664000000,26.50]
```

This is my current PHP code:

```
$supplied = $service->getSupplied();

if (count($supplied)>0) {

    foreach ($supplied as $key=>$value) {

            $chart_data['data'][] = $value['DATE_JAVASCRIPT'].','.$value['SUPPLIED_AMOUNT'];    

    }

}
```

But it render a similar JSON:

```
 "data": [
        "1437004800000,5919.00",
        "1437091200000,4389.00",
        "1437177600000,12069.00",
        "1437350400000,10220.00",
        "1437436800000,9444.00"]
```

Thank you very much

Comment: The "JSON" you want to generate is not valid. There must be a top level data structure. A bunch of comma separated arrays is not JSON.

Comment: @Quentin: it is valid json. the question would be why OP wants a bunch of csv strings in an array...

Comment: does removing the ['data'] from your assignment get your desired json?

Comment: @MarcB — Error: Parse error on line 1:
...253145600000, 26.36], [1253232000000, 26
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', got ','

Comment: Avoid any errors and take advantage of [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). The only thing you need is to correctly form your array with the key you need. Then use this function to format your array into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `['data']` into your array, then:

```
        $chart_data[] = array($value['DATE_JAVASCRIPT'],$value['SUPPLIED_AMOUNT']);
                  ^^^^
```

And note the change to `array()`. You're embedding what amounts to CSV strings in your array, which seems weird...

Answer (score 0):

This part of code should work:

```
foreach ($supplied as $key=>$value) {
    $chart_data[] = [$value['DATE_JAVASCRIPT'],$value['SUPPLIED_AMOUNT']];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$chart_data['data'][] = [$value['DATE_JAVASCRIPT'].','.$value['SUPPLIED_AMOUNT']];
```

If you don't need 'data':

```
$chart_data[] = [$value['DATE_JAVASCRIPT'].','.$value['SUPPLIED_AMOUNT']];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take part of `json_encode`, by formatting your array and using this function to take back a well formatted JSON file. It will avoid some code misconception and errors :

```
$supplied = $service->getSupplied();

if (count($supplied)>0) {
    foreach ($supplied as $key=>$value) {
        $date = $value['DATE_JAVASCRIPT'];
        $supplied_amount = $value['SUPPLIED_AMOUNT'];
        $chart_data[] = [$date, $supplied_amount];
    }

    $chart_data = json_encode($chart_data);

    print_r($chart_data);

    # chart_data : example of JSON output
    #   [
    #       [12092016, 12.80],
    #       [12122016, 57.90],
    #       [12112016, 48.81]
    #   ]
}
```